# Can text tabs be made viewable for carbon copy recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope which utilizes a template with read only text tabs. Using the Java API, I am able to initialize these tabs with dynamic values for each envelope created. These text tabs include information such as customer first name, customer last name, etc.

I have one recipient with signing order 1 and role 'Receives a Copy' (the agent) and another recipient with signing order 2 and role 'Needs to Sign' (the customer).

The issue I am having is that, upon initial CC to the agent, all of the dynamic read-only text tabs are empty. Is it possible for the CC recipient to receive these fields with data upon initial send of the document? Otherwise, is there an alternative way to fill in dynamic data within a document so that CC recipients can see the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you are looking for is under Settings > Sending Settings > *When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients.*

With that checked, the pre-populated fields will appear even if the role they are assigned to has not taken action.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion. What about if you reverse the signing order for the 2 recipients. In my opinion "Receives a Copy" role should receive completed document. If the agent need to approve it first, then perhaps you should use different role for the agent. The dynamic read-only fields are related only to the customer and will be visible to the CC only when signed by the customer